# How to sortBy and groupBy with the same List in kotlin

Tags: android, list, kotlin, mutablelist

I have a list which have elements which have a header, I use a groupBy to group all the list elements by one header, this is working nice, but , now I also want to sortBy the elements which hasDisscount is true, because I want this elements to be shown first in the list

```
 fun setItems(listProduct: MutableList<Product>) {
        listProduct.sortBy { it.hasDisscount }
        listProduct.groupBy({ it.productTypeName }, { product -> product
        }).iterator().forEach {
            uiItems.add(it.key)
            for (product in it.value) {
                uiItems.add(product)
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

Now, I have tried to first sort the list with elements that hasDisscount is true first before grouping, but is not working, my disscount elements are shown at the bottom of my List

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding

```
   listProduct.sortByDescending { it.hasDisscount }
```